# Keep buttons alignment in HTML

Tags: html, angular

Everytime when I press on `Button 1`, `Button 2` and `Button 3` are going below `Button 1` (same with `Button 2`). [Here is a working snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6v3bon)

I want something like this to happen (everytime I press on a new button, the new text overrides the previous text, and the alignment is kept).

[image: I want something like this to happen]

What do I need to change in order to achieve what I want? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Your code does not run

Comment: What about now, @mplungjan ?

Comment: No. Localhost errors and `(index):12 Uncaught ReferenceError: _preboot is not defined`

Comment: I don't know, it's working fine. I tried on a different browser.

Comment: @Tenzolinho Are you using any css framework? Like bootstrap.

Comment: @Nik I do, I just wanted to keep it simple.

Comment: @Tenzolinho Oh, OK. Can you check my answer? Just curious if that helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structure you html like this. 
[image]

Place the text inside the container element for each button.

Set the container elements display to inline-block

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for you :

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tab button {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: ya just changed through javascript and simply taken tabs using bootstarp @mplungjan

Comment: yeah Mr. @mplungjan sure for  every time i post the answer thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the div's which are containing the text to display: inline-block;

```
div {
  display: inline-block
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6v3bon?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) is the updated code snippet. I've restructured the html and took the text div at the end after buttons are added. This way the buttons remain in same position. For replacing the text, I've used a variable which is changed on button click and the value is updated on html.

Hope this is what you wanted to achieve.